# assembly masm number of occurence

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32, irvine32

I have an  array of 10 int and I am trying to write a loop to calculate a number of occurrence of a specific integer which I stored in a variable in x86 assembly using the Irvine32 library

the int i want to calculate number of occurrence of it is stored in "maxi"
the var where i will count in is "numofocc"
array 's type is word so i add 2 to the array to move to the next place

```
mov ecx ,10                                   
 L:         
  cmp maxi , [array]  
  je count    
  add array ,2     
 count:    
  add  numofocc ,1    
  add array ,2     
 loop L
```

Comment: Please provide some marked up code and describe the problem.

Comment: As far as I know memory-to-memory operands like `cmp maxi, [array]` are not allowed. Also you have incremented the array address twice (each time by 2) and the branch test does not skip the incrementing of `numofocc`, which is always done.

Comment: but by adding these brackets [] to array we access the first  element stored in the array not the addrees so it is allowed ?

Comment: also i incremented it twice becouse the two cases if the number is equal or not it should pass to the next element

Comment: The branch should skip `add  numofocc, 1` and the first `add array, 2` can be removed, because you must always advance the array pointer.

Comment: sorry , what is the meaning of The branch should skip add numofocc, 1?

Comment: The loop does 2 things. If the element value matches, you should increment the counter but if not the branch test should skip over that one instruction with `jne` not with `je`. Then the array pointer is advanced.

Comment: `add array, 2` increments the first element (in MASM, a label is a memory reference even without `[]`, unless you use `mov edx, OFFSET array`.  Unlike in NASM).  You can't change label addresses at runtime.  Get the address in a register.  Unless you have some unusual macro definitions, this won't assemble because `maxi` and `[array]` are both memory locations.  There's no `cmp immediate, [memory]`, only [`cmp [mem], imm`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CMP.html), so `maxi` can't be an `equ` assemble-time constant.

Comment: [Test if value in EAX is the same as any value in a array x86](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7736884) shows how to loop over an array.  It's looking for the *first* match, but skipping over an `add` isn't your problem; everything else is, and that question covers it.